# how to do SVN http-request checkin/commit within html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, svn

i've got a problem

i want to use a website to do a checkin and checkout on my svn server.
i already got everthing to the point where i can do a checkout using jQuery.
my remaining problem is with the handling of the MERGE process.
within the MERGE svn transmits a chunked response.
but my console just reports Bad Request.
wireshark told m that the Transfer-Encoding is chunked.
but i couldn't set it to chunked. if i set the contentType to chunked the body is chunked not the transfere-encoding.
and jquery.ajax() doesn't provide something as Transfer-Encoding.
trying to put it into the headers didn't work as well...it didn't even show this header

my checkin code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "OPTIONS",
        url: baseURL,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:options xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:activity-collection-set></D:activity-collection-set></D:options>',
        success: function(data1, status, jqxhr){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseURL + "/!svn/me",
                contentType: "application/vnd.svn-skel",
                data: "(create-txn-with-props (svn:txn-user-agent 40 SVN/1.8.9(i686-pc-linux-gnu) serf/1.3.4 svn:log function svn:txn-client-compat-version 5 1.8.9))",
                success: function(data2, status, jqxhr){
                    rev = jqxhr.getResponseHeader('SVN-Txn-Name');
                    newdata = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlString["context"]);
                    hashResult = calcMD5(newdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "PUT",
                        url: baseURL + "/!svn/txr/" + rev + file + ".xml",
                        headers: {"X-SVN-Version-Name": latestRev, "X-SVN-Base-Fulltext-MD5":hashBase, "X-SVN-Result-Fulltext-MD5": hashResult},
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        data: newdata,
                        success: function(data3, status, jqxhr){
                            chunked1 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><D:merge xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:source><D:href>/svn/check/!svn/txn/' + rev + '</D:href></D:source><D:no-auto-merge></D:no-auto-merge><D:no-checkout></D:no-checkout><D:prop><D:checked-in></D:checked-in><D:version-name></D:version-name><D:resourcetype></D:resourcetype><D:creationdate></D:creationdate><D:creator-displayname>';
                            chunked2 = '</D:creator-displayname></D:prop></D:merge>';
                            length1 = chunked1.length;
                            length2 = chunked2.length;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "MERGE",
                                url: baseURL,
                                headers: {"X-SVN-Options": "release-locks"},
                                contentType: "text/xml",
                                data: length1 + chunked1 + length2 + chunked2,
                                success: function(data4, status, jqxhr){
                                    alert('file submitted');
                                },
                                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert(textStatus + ' at MERGE \n' + textStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus + ' at PUT\n' + textStatus);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "DELETE",
                                url: baseURL + "/!svn/txn/" + rev,
                                success: function(data3, status, jqxhr){
                                    alert('file deleted');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ' at POST\n' + textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ' at OPTIONS\n' + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: corrected some mistakes in my code
changed the problemfocus from PUT to MERGE, because i found the problem
the problem was that i transmitted within the "X-SVN-Version-Name" not just the number but 'number', therefore the error "File is out of Date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `contentType: "text/xml"` and `data: chunked1 + chunked2`

than everything works fine and svn accepts the file